# Hazelcast Caching for Clusterd Spring Application

Tags: caching, hazelcast

We recently clusterd our Spring application with 2 nodes backed by one database.
Our application has Dynamic menu(each user has different menu options), since we dont have enough caching in place every time user logs we hit the database and filter the Menu options based on user security. We want to avoid hitting the database each time user logs in by introducing Cache.

I was reading about hazelcast cache `http://hazelcast.org/use-cases/caching/`  and I noticed multiple options available for caching like `In-Memory Data Grid/NoSql`, `Jcache` and `Spring Cache` but not really sure which one is the best solution to cache the Menu items(String type). From my understanding I felt `Spring Cache` is the correct solution for my use case, if not please suggest me other hazelcast caching options.

Comment: dear RanPaul, kindly accept the answer if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 5):

Spring Caching supports Hazelcast (or Hazelcast provides integration with Spring Caching `:)` ). 
If you use **Spring 4** and higher, you can use [`JCache` caching](https://spring.io/blog/2014/04/14/cache-abstraction-jcache-jsr-107-annotations-support) support from Spring Framework.
You can find examples of usage [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration). 
Look for `spring-*` projects.

Spring Boot also supported. Watch the webinar [recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXHDRAuV2wQ), read my [blog post](http://next.javaheadbrain.com/posts/2015/12/31/caching-made-bootiful.html), find code samples [here](https://github.com/gAmUssA/caching-made-bootiful-webinar).

Let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you