# spring hazelcast cache cluster showing warning

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast, spring-cache

I have micro service architecture and all the micro services are using the same database. Now i want to have distributed cache in my architecture. For the moment i choose Hazelnut for distributed. As a start i put the following configuration in all my microservices.

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@AutoConfigureBefore(value = { DatabaseConfiguration.class })
public class CacheConfiguration {

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CacheConfiguration.class);

    @Value("${cache.timeToLiveSeconds:3600}")
    private final int timeToLiveSeconds = 3600;

    @Value("${cache.backupCount:1}")
    private final int backupCount = 1;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        LOG.info("Closing Cache Manager");
        Hazelcast.shutdownAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(final HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
        LOG.debug("Starting HazelcastCacheManager");
        return new HazelcastCacheManager(hazelcastInstance);
    }

    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
        LOG.debug("Configuring Hazelcast");
        final HazelcastInstance hazelCastInstance = Hazelcast
                .getHazelcastInstanceByName("caching_service");
        if (hazelCastInstance != null) {
            LOG.debug("Hazelcast already initialized");
            return hazelCastInstance;
        }
        final Config config = new Config();
        config.setInstanceName("caching_service");
        config.getNetworkConfig().setPort(5701);
        config.getNetworkConfig().setPortAutoIncrement(true);

        // In development, remove multicast auto-configuration
        if (env.acceptsProfiles(Constants.DEV)) {
            System.setProperty("hazelcast.local.localAddress", "127.0.0.1");

            config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getAwsConfig().setEnabled(false);
            config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
            config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(false);
        }

        config.getMapConfigs().put("default", initializeDefaultMapConfig());
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
    }

    private MapConfig initializeDefaultMapConfig() {
        final MapConfig mapConfig = new MapConfig();

        /*
         * Number of backups. If 1 is set as the backup-count for example, then all
         * entries of the map will be copied to another JVM for fail-safety. Valid numbers
         * are 0 (no backup), 1, 2, 3.
         */
        mapConfig.setBackupCount(0);

        /*
         * Valid values are: NONE (no eviction), LRU (Least Recently Used), LFU (Least
         * Frequently Used). NONE is the default.
         */
        mapConfig.setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU);

        /*
         * Maximum size of the map. When max size is reached, map is evicted based on the
         * policy defined. Any integer between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE. 0 means
         * Integer.MAX_VALUE. Default is 0.
         */
        mapConfig.setMaxSizeConfig(
                new MaxSizeConfig(0, MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.USED_HEAP_SIZE));

        return mapConfig;
    }
}
```

Now i started my first micro service and the logs lines were

```
2017-07-16 10:38:06.581  INFO 13084 --- [           main] c.h.instance.DefaultAddressPicker        : [LOCAL] [dev] [3.7.7] Picked [127.0.0.1]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5701], bind any local is true
2017-07-16 10:38:06.595  INFO 13084 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.system                     : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] Hazelcast 3.7.7 (20170404 - e3c56ea) starting at [127.0.0.1]:5701
2017-07-16 10:38:06.595  INFO 13084 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.system                     : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
2017-07-16 10:38:06.595  INFO 13084 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.system                     : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] Configured Hazelcast Serialization version : 1
2017-07-16 10:38:06.769  INFO 13084 --- [           main] c.h.s.i.o.impl.BackpressureRegulator     : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] Backpressure is disabled
2017-07-16 10:38:07.171 DEBUG 13084 --- [           main] c.h.internal.cluster.ClusterService      : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] Updating members [Member [127.0.0.1]:5701 - b2e3c44d-0392-4813-a2c8-d648695e8f1d this]
2017-07-16 10:38:07.171 DEBUG 13084 --- [           main] c.h.i.p.InternalPartitionService         : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] Adding Member [127.0.0.1]:5701 - b2e3c44d-0392-4813-a2c8-d648695e8f1d this
2017-07-16 10:38:07.293  INFO 13084 --- [           main] c.h.s.i.o.impl.OperationExecutorImpl     : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] Starting 8 partition threads
2017-07-16 10:38:07.295  INFO 13084 --- [           main] c.h.s.i.o.impl.OperationExecutorImpl     : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] Starting 5 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
2017-07-16 10:38:07.302  INFO 13084 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] [127.0.0.1]:5701 is STARTING
2017-07-16 10:38:07.302 DEBUG 13084 --- [           main] c.h.i.p.InternalPartitionService         : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] Adding Member [127.0.0.1]:5701 - b2e3c44d-0392-4813-a2c8-d648695e8f1d this
2017-07-16 10:38:07.303  INFO 13084 --- [           main] c.h.n.t.n.NonBlockingIOThreadingModel    : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] TcpIpConnectionManager configured with Non Blocking IO-threading model: 3 input threads and 3 output threads
2017-07-16 10:38:07.305 DEBUG 13084 --- [           main] c.h.n.t.n.NonBlockingIOThreadingModel    : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] IO threads selector mode is SELECT
2017-07-16 10:38:07.317  WARN 13084 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] No join method is enabled! Starting standalone.
2017-07-16 10:38:07.351  INFO 13084 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] [127.0.0.1]:5701 is STARTED
```

Now i started my second micro service

```
2017-07-16 10:41:30.841  INFO 17936 --- [           main] c.h.instance.DefaultAddressPicker        : [LOCAL] [dev] [3.7.7] Picked [127.0.0.1]:5702, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5702], bind any local is true
2017-07-16 10:41:30.854  INFO 17936 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.system                     : [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] Hazelcast 3.7.7 (20170404 - e3c56ea) starting at [127.0.0.1]:5702
2017-07-16 10:41:30.855  INFO 17936 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.system                     : [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
2017-07-16 10:41:30.855  INFO 17936 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.system                     : [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] Configured Hazelcast Serialization version : 1
2017-07-16 10:41:31.017  INFO 17936 --- [           main] c.h.s.i.o.impl.BackpressureRegulator     : [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] Backpressure is disabled
2017-07-16 10:41:31.451 DEBUG 17936 --- [           main] c.h.internal.cluster.ClusterService      : [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] Updating members [Member [127.0.0.1]:5702 - db64274e-73bd-4aa2-ae67-f626433b25c6 this]
2017-07-16 10:41:31.452 DEBUG 17936 --- [           main] c.h.i.p.InternalPartitionService         : [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] Adding Member [127.0.0.1]:5702 - db64274e-73bd-4aa2-ae67-f626433b25c6 this
2017-07-16 10:41:31.582  INFO 17936 --- [           main] c.h.s.i.o.impl.OperationExecutorImpl     : [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] Starting 8 partition threads
2017-07-16 10:41:31.583  INFO 17936 --- [           main] c.h.s.i.o.impl.OperationExecutorImpl     : [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] Starting 5 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
2017-07-16 10:41:31.590  INFO 17936 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] [127.0.0.1]:5702 is STARTING
2017-07-16 10:41:31.591 DEBUG 17936 --- [           main] c.h.i.p.InternalPartitionService         : [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] Adding Member [127.0.0.1]:5702 - db64274e-73bd-4aa2-ae67-f626433b25c6 this
2017-07-16 10:41:31.591  INFO 17936 --- [           main] c.h.n.t.n.NonBlockingIOThreadingModel    : [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] TcpIpConnectionManager configured with Non Blocking IO-threading model: 3 input threads and 3 output threads
2017-07-16 10:41:31.592 DEBUG 17936 --- [           main] c.h.n.t.n.NonBlockingIOThreadingModel    : [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] IO threads selector mode is SELECT
2017-07-16 10:41:31.633  WARN 17936 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] No join method is enabled! Starting standalone.
2017-07-16 10:41:31.633  WARN 17936 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] Config seed port is 5701 and cluster size is 1. Some of the ports seem occupied!
2017-07-16 10:41:31.663  INFO 17936 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] [127.0.0.1]:5702 is STARTED
```

so i wanted to know if i am doing things right here since i get this line after started second microservice

```
[127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] Config seed port is 5701 and cluster size is 1. Some of the ports seem occupied!
```

I have the following queries

1.) Is the the right way to created Hazelcast spring distributed cache mechanism ?

2.) When i say distributed does it mean that if i have same entity cache in both the micro services , doing CRUD on entity in one micro
    service will update the cache in other micro services for the same
    entity as well.

3.) If i don't want to use spring cache annotations like Cacheable etc... can i remove EnableCaching or it is not a good idea. I want
    to create cache programmatically and manage cache programmatically and not
    by annotations.

Comment: @Marged yep. This is not an answer. An author of this question asking about hazelcast. Your plug of geode is not appropriate. Thank you

Comment: @VicGamov: This is why I put it as a comment ;-) I just wanted to "warn" the OP because I tried the same way he does and ended switching to Gemfire / Geode when I learned about the deficiencies of Hazelcast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely hazecast can work in your use case. 
Check this answer to similar question 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38247515/27563

Check this [blogpost](http://gamov.io/posts/2015/12/31/caching-made-bootiful.html) with caching example for spring boot.